# Report errors not asked by the user

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, ethics

A user posted his/her [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20470812/combine-classes) and asked a question regarding a specific section. However, it is clear from whatsoever code he/she posted that the program inherently has several other bugs. However, the answers given are restricted only to that specific query and not for other errors. Is it some kind of protocol being followed?

Comment: It is good to explain why a user is wrong or in other words to go above what's asked. But the OP doesn't seem to have a clear insight on how his program works, he didn't try anything - essentially he dumped his code in the hopes anyone would do his work for him, IMHO.

Comment: That is a really bad example question - it is a typo issue and as such the question is not helpful to others. It should get closed and eventually deleted.

Comment: Came 2 meta.stackoverflow for the first time with what I believe was a valid question...and I get downvoted..:-/ :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By all means, if you see additional issues in the question, add details about them to your answer.

That is - make sure you **are** answering the question first (a "don't do that and here is why" or "you are solving the wrong problem and this is why" are OK) - address the other issues later on.

---

If you are not answering, you can point out issues in comments - this is fine.

For example: the SQL tag is full of "your code is open to SQL Injection" in comments (and sometimes, in answers).